The Proper Way To Apply Transformations in WinUi?
at msdn you can see an example of how to do this in the .xaml file. But what is the correct approach to apply matrix transformations in the code behind? For example rotating a rectangle or applying a render transform like the example?
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red">
<Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    <MatrixTransform Matrix="1,0,0,1,200,0">
    </MatrixTransform>
</Rectangle.RenderTransform>


For more details about Transformations in WinUi3 you could refer to the Doc:Transforms overview

The following sample code works. Just make sure to use the right Rectangle and not the wrong Rectangle.
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Shapes;

namespace WinUIApp;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage _Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The Rectangle's namespace is
        // Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Shapes and not System.Drawing.
        var rectangle = new Rectangle()
        {
            Width = 100,
            Height = 100,
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
            RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform()
            {
                Matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 200, 0)
            }
        };

        this.Content = rectangle;
    }
}


If this helped, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session. : )
